# Is it possible to create an array of arrays in WinRT with C++/CX?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am messing around with this topic a day now. I tried to use `Vectors`, `IVectors` and `Arrays`.

`Arrays` can't have a higher dimension than 1 in WinRT, `Vectors` seem to be impossible to use in a public context. (If you can tell me how, please do!) and `IVectors` are interfaces, so you can't make an `IVector` of `IVectors`.

**Is there *any*, and I mean *any* way to make a real two-dimensional array or an array of arrays like it was possible in C++/CLI?**

(And yes, I know I can simulate 2 dimensions with a one dimensional array, but I don't really want to do that.)

Comment: Use the types available to you from C++.

Comment: after a lot of research I found out there is a keyword internal, which enables me to use STL types in a kind-of public context. so finally, @HansPassant your answer actually solved my problem, despite it wasn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: Can you explain how can you use "internal" in winrt to use STL types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this workaround for this issue. Not pretty, but functional.

Rather than creating a Vector of Vectors create a Vector of Objects. Then use safe_cast to access Vectors within your containing Vector.

```
Platform::Collections::Vector<Object^ >^ lArrayWithinArray = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Object^ >();

//Prepare some test data
Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^ lStrings = ref new  Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
lStrings->Append(L"One");
lStrings->Append(L"Two");
lStrings->Append(L"Three");
lStrings->Append(L"Four");
lStrings->Append(L"Five");

//We will use this to show that it works
Platform::String^ lOutput = L"";

//Populate the containing Vector
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    lArrayWithinArray->Append(ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<String^>());

    //Populate each Vector within the containing Vector with test data
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        //Use safe_cast to cast the Object as a Vector
        safe_cast<Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^>(lArrayWithinArray->GetAt(i))->Append(lStrings->GetAt(j));
    }
}

//Test loop to verify our content
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        lOutput += lStrings->GetAt(i) + L":" + safe_cast<Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^>(lArrayWithinArray->GetAt(i))->GetAt(j) + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this out and it works nicely! I think for small vectors you won't have to care about efficiency.
The solution for my problem was more like just using STL vectors.
Anyway, this workaround seems to do nicely when you really need to pass multidimensional vectors via the ABI.